# How to get Hibernate to do no more than one SQL query per a parent/child relationship on WebLogic 10g?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, weblogic

We need to get back a collection of Widgets, where each widget can contain zero or more Fidgets.  Our problem is that whenever we run `from Widget`, Hibernate generates one SQL query for each Fidget on each Widget.  So If I have one Widget with 19 Fidgets, Hibernate runs 20 SQL queries!  I would have expected only two queries: one for the Widget and one for the Fidgets.

We have SQL Server 2005 and WebLogic 10g.

My relevant Spring Configuration:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSourceA" jndi-name="jdbc/dataSourceA" />
<bean id="sessionFactoryA" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceA" />
    <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
            <value>com/mycompany/database/Widget.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>com/mycompany/database/Fidget.hbm.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <value>
            hibernate.query.factory_class=org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory
            hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
            hibernate.show_sql=true
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="transactionManagerA" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactoryA" />
</bean>
```

My Widget.hbm.xml:

```
<class name="Widget" package="com.mycompany.database">
    <id name="id" column="ID" type="integer">
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    ...
    <set name="fidgets" table="Fidget" lazy="false">
        <key column="WidgetID" />
        <one-to-many class="Fidget" />
    </set>
</class>
```

My Fidget.hbm.xml:

```
<class name="Fidget" package="com.mycompany.database">
    <id name="id" column="ID" type="integer">
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    ...
    <many-to-one name="widget" column="WidgetID" class="Widget" lazy="false" />
</class>
```

The following SQL is generated by Hibernate for a Widget with four Fidgets and a Widget with six Fidgets:

```
select fidget_.Col1, fidget_.Col2, ... from Fidget fidget_ where fidget_.WidgetID = 7
select fidget_.Col1, fidget_.Col2, ... from Fidget fidget_ where fidget_.WidgetID = 7
select fidget_.Col1, fidget_.Col2, ... from Fidget fidget_ where fidget_.WidgetID = 7
select fidget_.Col1, fidget_.Col2, ... from Fidget fidget_ where fidget_.WidgetID = 7
select fidget_.Col1, fidget_.Col2, ... from Fidget fidget_ where fidget_.WidgetID = 8
select fidget_.Col1, fidget_.Col2, ... from Fidget fidget_ where fidget_.WidgetID = 8
select fidget_.Col1, fidget_.Col2, ... from Fidget fidget_ where fidget_.WidgetID = 8
select fidget_.Col1, fidget_.Col2, ... from Fidget fidget_ where fidget_.WidgetID = 8
select fidget_.Col1, fidget_.Col2, ... from Fidget fidget_ where fidget_.WidgetID = 8
select fidget_.Col1, fidget_.Col2, ... from Fidget fidget_ where fidget_.WidgetID = 8
```

Comment: The question title is a bit misleading. Search for "hibernate n+1 select"; this is well-documented.

Comment: the problem/answer here has nothing to do with Weblogic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable [batch fetching](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#performance-fetching-batch) in the Hibernate configuration to reduce the number of queries, or execute a query that will load the Widgets and their Fidgets:

```
select w from Widget w left join fetch w.fidgets where ...
```

This is also well described in the [reference documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-joins), which is a great source of information.

Comment: Thanks for the reference!  By adding `fetch` to the end of the join I was able to get it down to one SQL query.